# CircleCI cannot find maven settings when supplied on CLI

Tags: maven, kubernetes, circleci, argo

[ERROR] Error executing Maven.

[ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: /home/circleci/project/ .folder/mvn-settings.xml

I have a script build-project.sh to build a mvn project.
This script takes the environment variable `CUSTOM_MVN_OPTS`, where I specify the path to the custom settings (e.g. private repo locations, etc.).

When I run the script in CircleCI or any CICD pipeline under docker env it's throwing above error.

```
#!/bin/sh
# build-project.sh

mvn ${CUSTOM_MVN_OPTS} package
```

What I expect? `build-project.sh` to build artifacts.

```
CUSTOM_MVN_OPTS="-s .folder/mvn-settings.xml" build-project.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging found the solution.

Fix: hardcode the `-s` option within the script, you cannot pass this thru env variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
# build-project.sh

if [ -z "${CUSTOM_MVN_OPTS}" ]; then
  mvn package
else 
  mvn -s ${CUSTOM_MVN_OPTS} package
fi
```